# Save data on exit Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal Apps)

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have a question regarding saving/loading data in Windows Universal Apps 8.1.

I cannot seem to save the data when exiting the app. My call to the serialization is done in the `OnSuspending` method in App.xaml.cs, but I don't think it is called whenever I close the app.

It sometimes saves the data, sometimes not. Here is my code for OnSuspending and Save methods.

```
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            // TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
            Debug.WriteLine("SUSPENDING");
            HabitManager.HabitSerializer.Save();
            deferral.Complete();
        }


public async static void Save()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("SAVED");
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(HabitList.Instance.GetHabits());
        var habits = HabitList.Instance.GetHabits();
        foreach (var h in habits)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("S: " + h);
        }
        StorageFile saveFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(saveFile, json);

    }
```

So my question is, what could be the problem, and if this isn't a good serializing mechanism, can you suggest me a better one? Thank you

Comment: Are you saving a lot? There's a time limit on how long `OnSuspending` is allow to run.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen Not really, I just want it to save when I exit the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OnSuspending call returns before the Save call finishes.

Change Save to return a Task so you can await it:

```
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    // TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
    Debug.WriteLine("SUSPENDING");
    // Wait fir Save to finish its a sync operations
    await HabitManager.HabitSerializer.Save();
    deferral.Complete();
}

public async static Task Save()
{
    // Same save code
}
```

Also be careful when testing suspension. The app won't suspend normally while debugging, but VS provides a suspend button to simulate the suspension process.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my code like that yesterday, but forgot to update my answer.